# How to set font type and size for printing using windows GDI?

Tags: python, printing, gdi, pywin32

My python program only needs to print text in certain positions. I'm using the windows GDI to archive the goal.

The following code does the job, but i need to set the font type and the size.

```
import win32ui
dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
dc.CreatePrinterDC()
dc.StartDoc('Test document')

dc.StartPage()
dc.TextOut(100,2000, 'HELLO WORLD!')
dc.EndPage()
dc.EndDoc()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CreateFont](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/pywin32/win32ui__CreateFont_meth.html) and then select the font in to device context, example:

```
dc.StartPage()

fontdata = { 'name':'Arial', 'height':100, 'italic':True, 'weight':win32con.FW_NORMAL}
font = win32ui.CreateFont(fontdata);
dc.SelectObject(font)
dc.TextOut(100,2000, 'HELLO WORLD!')
...
```

To make a better calculation for font size, use the following based on `CreateFont` WinAPI reference:

```
def getfontsize(dc, PointSize):
    inch_y = dc.GetDeviceCaps(win32con.LOGPIXELSY)
    return int(-(PointSize * inch_y) / 72)
```

Example: now you can use this to draw with font size 11 at the center of the page

```
fontsize = getfontsize(dc, 11)
fontdata = { 'name':'Consolas', 'height':fontsize}
font = win32ui.CreateFont(fontdata);
dc.SelectObject(font)
```

Also, `LOGPIXELSY`/`LOGPIXELSY` and `PHYSICALWIDTH`/`PHYSICALHEIGHT` can be used to calculate the coordinates more accurately.

Comment: Edit, added improved formula for calculating font size based on point size